# Android streaming screen

Tags: android, ffmpeg, ffserver

Im able to share screen via ffmpeg
`./ffmpeg -f fbdev -r 24 -i /dev/graphics/fb0 http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm`

But the output live stream is very slow. 
Following is the conf file which I'm using.

```
`Port 8090
RTSPPort 7654
BindAddress 0.0.0.0
RTSPBindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 1000
CustomLog -
NoDaemon
<Feed live1.ffm>
File /data/live1.ffm
FileMaxSize 40M
NoAudio
ACL allow 127.0.0.1
</Feed>
<Stream live.mp4>
Feed live1.ffm
Format mpeg2video
NoAudio
VideoBitRate 1024
VideoFrameRate 1
VideoBufferSize 10000
VideoSize 480x800
VideoQMin 1
VideoQMax 15
</Stream>`
```

Kindly let me know how should I change my conf file to get a fast video output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot achieve a satisfied performance with pure CPU power doing the video encode. So, try to find out some other solutions using hardware encoder.

Comment: do you suggest any hardware encoder api? i m clueless in this.